Mirror code snippet that generates key and initialization vector in PHP
I have a method written in C# that generates a Key and Initialization Vector and uses them to encrypt data. I am trying to mirror that method to PHP implementation, but the problem is the different encrypted values generated from C# and PHP. I did the investigation and found that the Key and IV used for encryption are different in the two implementations.
Below are the corresponding code blocks used to generate key and IV in C# and PHP.
C# code snippet
string password = 'pass here';
byte[] salt = new byte[] { 0x43, 0x87, 0x23, 0x72, 0x45, 0x56, 0x68, 0x14, 0x62, 0x84 };
PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, salt);
aesAlg.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
aesAlg.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
Console.WriteLine("Key: " + BitConverter.ToString(aesAlg.Key).Replace("-", ""));
Console.WriteLine("IV: " + BitConverter.ToString(aesAlg.IV).Replace("-", ""));

PHP code snippet
$password = 'pass here';
$salt = hex2bin('43872372455668146284');
$keyLength = 32; // 32 bytes for AES-256 key
$ivLength = 16;  // 16 bytes for AES block size
$combinedLength = $keyLength + $ivLength;
$derivedBytes = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $password, $salt, 100, $combinedLength, true);
$key = substr($derivedBytes, 0, $keyLength);
$iv = substr($derivedBytes, $keyLength, $ivLength);
echo "Key: " . bin2hex($key) . "\n";
echo "IV: " . bin2hex($iv) . "\n";

Does anyone notice what is different in that two implementations that cause code to generate different key and IV?

My guess would be endian-ness issues with how you're trying to directly create a byte array from the hex string, rather than using a method such as Convert.FromHexString().

The key derivation functions are different: PasswordDeriveBytes() in C# code implements an MS proprietary extension of PBKDF1, while in the PHP code PBKDF2 is used.

@Topaco, that is correct. I was able to mirror it with pbkdf1. Thanks!

PasswordDeriveBytes is an MS extension of PBKDF1, which only gives the same result as PBKDF1 for a maximum key size of 20 bytes (for SHA1, the default) and an 8 bytes salt, and should not be used at all for security reasons (instead PBKDF2 or more modern algorithms). If you absolutely need it (e.g. for legacy applications), there are PHP ports on the web.
